# How to use bundles like in old mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm migrating a old MVC application to new asp.net core and I'm dealing with the new `bundleconfig.json` and how it works.

In the old code I used to have something like this:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/appcomponents").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/js/jquery.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/modernizr.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/detect.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/fastclick.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/jquery.slimscroll.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/jquery.blockUI.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/waves.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/wow.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/jquery.nicescroll.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"));
```

And in my `CSHTML` file I just added `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/appcomponents")`

And I can had multiple bundles so depending on the view I could reference a different bundle depending on the files required for that module or view.

In Asp.Net Core I don't know how to do that.

I saw that you can add the files for CSS and JS but just once, like I don't see a way to have multiple bundles. In that case not all the modules uses the same CSS files and JS files so doesn't make sense to always pulls everything, what it makes more sense is to just use the required files for that module of view and thus from the `bundleconfig.json` a way to have multiple bundles just as in the old mvc projects.

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/main.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css",
      "wwwroot/css/abc01.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/main.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js",
      "wwwroot/js/abc01.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

Also, if I'm running based on development, can I just reference my script as:

```
<script src="~/js/main.min.js"></script>
```

Because I think `main.min.js` is only generated when building for production. So if that's correct, how do you reference when dev? Do I have to include in my views all the scripts and css using the Environment Include tag? and then use Environment exclude tag for the `main.min.js`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bundling in ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC dev vs prod environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57225528/bundling-in-asp-net-core-2-2-mvc-dev-vs-prod-environments)

Comment: *like I dont see a way to have multiple bundles*: why not create multiple sections like `{outputFileName:'...',inputFiles:[...]}, {outputFileName:'...',inputFiles:[...]}`?